# How do I extract the data from these JavaScript tables using Selenium and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Python, JavaScript, and Web-Scraping. I am trying to write code that writes all of the data in tables like this into a csv file. The webpage is "https://www.mcmaster.com/cam-lock-fittings/material~aluminum/"

[image]

I started by trying to find the data in the html but then realized that the website uses JavaScript. I then tried using selenium but I cannot find anywhere in the JavaScript code that has the actual data that is displayed in these tables. I wrote this code to see if I could find the display data anywhere but I was unable to find it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.mcmaster.com/cam-lock-fittings/material~aluminum/'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Brian Knoll/Desktop/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get(url)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.close()

filename = "McMaster Text.txt"
fo = open(filename, "w")
fo.write(html)
fo.close()
```

I'm sure there's an obvious answer that is just going over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to wait till the table your looking for is loaded.
To do so, add the following line to wait for 10 seconds before start scraping the data

```
fullLoad = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'ItmTblCntnr')]")))
```

Here is the full code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.mcmaster.com/cam-lock-fittings/material~aluminum/'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), options=options)

driver.get(url)
fullLoad = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'ItmTblCntnr')]")))

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.close()

filename = "McMaster Text.txt"
fo = open(filename, "w")
fo.write(html)
fo.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Rola. I got the following error:  NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: Put from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By at the top of your script. Will give you access to By.ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, AaronS. It ran that time but threw a timeout exception

Comment: @bknoll16 that's because the element doesn't exists, sorry i didn't notice the id is auto generated. i have modified my code, please try again now

Comment: @Rola thank you for your persistence with this. I am still getting a timeout exception with the updated code. Is everything working on your end?

Comment: @bknoll16 no worries. Yes it's running fine on my machine and the file was created successfully. not sure what could be the issue! are you calling same URL? try to kill chromedriver.exe process in your task manager and re-try

Comment: @Rola would you mind just posting a copy of your code? Still something weird happening over here.

Comment: @Rola thank you for doing that. Still not working. Maybe a permissions/User Agent issue? Either way thanks for your help. I'll probably just try to learn more about JavaScript before I take another stab at this

Comment: @bknoll16 mmmm,  at what line the error is returned? see my friend try to increase waiting time, change it to 15 or 20 seconds instead of 10

Comment: @Rola it says line 16 which is the "fullLoad" line. Just tried 20 seconds and it gave the same exception

Comment: @bknoll16 Can you share full exception details?